How to configure errorhandler to stop kafka listener after retries exceeded
I would like to configure an errorhandler for all @KafkaListeners in the application to make retries as it is done in the DefaultErrorHandler but instead of sending the message to a DLQ when the retries are exceeded, I would like to stop the listener container.
I am aware of the CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler, however this error handler does not have any retry mechanism. I also tried to create a Recoverer which stops the container but I am not able to access the listener container in there (only the consumer directly).
Any ideas how this could be configured correctly without hardcoding listener ids as suggested here How do you exit spring boot application programmatically when retries are exhausted, to prevent kafka offset commit ?
